# Simple Animated Content Replacement?

Tags: jquery, xhtml, slider, css-transitions

I need some advice on the best way to move forward or recommendations on stable plugins/solutions.

Basically:

1. I have 2 rows with 3 images each for a total of 6 images.
2. Each pic is a product.
3. Clicking on the Link will change the content to show you more information on the product.

The image below shows the before and after I am attempting to accomplish:

1. When clicking one of the 6 images, the content area should change so the layout is different.
2. The New layout is: **A.** An enlarged content area on the top. **B.** 5 thumbnails on the bottom.

[image: layout example]

Now I don't need anything fancy and what I would like to ultimately do is:

1. Show the "Before" state on page load. Once one of the images is clicked on, we never need to go back to this state.
2. Some how transition from the "before" state to the "after" state. I was thinking it could be as simple as having both states in a div with one being hidden and just have the "after" state either scroll up or bounce up so it either covers the "before" state or pushes it out the content area so it is now hidden.

   - Something similar to: 
     http://webdeveloperpost.com/Articles/Create-your-own-sliding-divs-with-jQuery.aspx
3. Once in the "after" state, clicking on the product images could just fade in/out the content area on top of it.
4. Although the product being shown should not appear on the bottom, hence why it is only showing 5 images instead of 6... I can definitely work with all 6 being on the bottom to make things easier.

---

Notes:

A. I was looking at these two tutorials, but they actually change all of the page content. This won't work for me because I have content to the left of what is shown in the example image and I don't want this to have to fade/load in and out:
- http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/comment-page-1/#comments

B. Thinking about it, maybe to keep things consistent, maybe it would be best to:

- slide in the "After" state from the bottom UP, pushing the "before" state out the way.
- Once in the "after" state, just sliding in the product information from left to right once a product image is clicked on.
- So the bottom only shows 5 product images, hide the div of the currently viewable product. However, I am thinking it might be easier to just always show all 6.

I am not sure how implementing the above would affect SEO, but I know no other way I can accomplish what I am doing aside from hiding a bunch of divs and utilizing jquery somehow.

Answer (score 2):

This is not difficult to make. I suggest that you have your images available as an array containing objects with data on each image. Then, on page load, create a "tile" for every image and place them in a box. Handle clicks on the tiles and move them around as you want, perhaps even creating a `div` for the product info.

I was bored so I made a small example for you using jQuery: [Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U2hqA/5/)

---

*Note:* I have only tested the above link in Chrome so there could be inconsistencies on Firefox, Opera etc.

Comment: First let me say, wow... if you did that while bored and called it a "small example" I can't imagine what you do when your actually working. That concept is awesome and worked on my firefox in osx. However I really need the transition from the "before" state to the "after" state to be the "after" sliding upwards and replacing the "before" state content. I have been searching for hours but only things I find are things related to images, or already styled, or have auto generated navigation.

Comment: @Damainman: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Try to phrase it so a monkey would understand.

Comment: To make it as simple as possible. The page loads on the "before" state with 6 images(products). Clicking any of the 6 images, creates a transition causing the "after" state to slide up and replace the "before" content so it displays the product information for the product that was clicked on. When on the "after" state, clicking on a thumbnail, causes the product description to slide in and replace the previous product description. Basically, a way to slide a div up and a way to slide a div from left to right with some type of easing effect.

Comment: @Damainman: All the technologies you need to do that is in my example. It's just a matter of changing the `left` property of an element that has a `transition` property set. Set the parent to `overflow: hidden` and you should be able to slide stuff in and out of it's bounds no problem